# How to set a string to an optional string value?

Tags: c++, string, stdoptional

Due to some constraint in the program(C++), I have a case where I am assigning an optional string to a string variable, which give the following error:
`error: no match for ‘operator=’ ...`

The piece of code is something like:

```
void blah(std::experimental::optional<std::string> foo, // more parameters)
{
    std::string bar;
    if(foo)
    {
        bar = foo; //error
    }

    // more code
}
```

*Attempts:*

I tried to convert the types to match by using:

```
bar = static_cast<std::string>(foo);
```

which ended up showing this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::experimental::optional<std::basic_string<char> >&)’
```

I am wondering:

1. Is there a way to handle this case?
2. Or else it is a design limitation and I have to use some other approach instead of assigning a optional string to a normal string?

Comment: Doc should help [std::experimental::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)/[std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (C++17).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several ways:

- ```
  /*const*/std::string bar = foo.value_or("some default value");
  ```
- ```
  std::string bar;
  if (foo) {
      bar = *foo;
  }
  ```
- ```
  std::string bar;
  if (foo) {
      bar = foo.value();
  }
  ```

Comment: [feel free to skip]A bit of follow up, even if the function parameter is optional, it always need a value for function call?

Comment: @DonBaka the parameter is not optional. It is a parameter of the type `std::[experimental::]optional`, and an object of that type can have the state of holding an object or not holding an object. `std::optional` is a type like  `std::vector`, `std::string`, …

Comment: Being the first argument to your function, you might want to consider the importance of this "optional" parameter in relation to the other parameters.  Usually, "opt-in" arguments are better as the trailing parameters and use either default values or function overloading.